# Can you lookup multiple documents by id within a single aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a user detail API view, and wish to add an `is_following` flag to indicate whether the authenticated API user (**user A**) is following the user who's profile they are viewing (**user B**).

At the time of the request I only have the authenticated API user's `_id`. I could fetch the `following` field for the authenticated API user in one query, and then continue to make a second query for the user they are interested in viewing, but I assume it would be more efficient to pass that work off to the database in a single aggregation (if possible).

Let's say I have the following schema for the `users` collection:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'David',
        following: [2, 3] // David follows Sam and Lucy
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        name: 'Sam',
        following: [1] // Sam only follows David
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        name: 'Lucy',
        following: [1, 2] // Lucy follows David and Sam
    },
]
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to write an aggregation in the way that I currently have in mind:

1. Match authenticated API user (**user A**) by `_id`
2. Store the `following` array for **user A** somehow within the aggregation pipeline for later use against the user we wish to view
3. Match again for a different user, the user who **user A** is interested in viewing (**user B**), by their `_id`
4. Using projection, append a new boolean field `is_following` which represents whether **user B**'s `_id` is within the authenticated API user (**user A**)'s `following` array which we stored earlier. i.e the logged in user is following the user who's profile they are currently viewing.

It's steps 2 and 3 which I'm uncertain of, I'm unsure if this approach of grabbing two documents with different `$match` criteria can be achieved within a single aggregation query.

**Edit: Adding expected output**

If the authenticated user (**user A**) was `_id` 2, and the viewed user, **user B**, was `_id` 1:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'David',
    following: [2, 3],
    is_following: true
}
```

If the authenticated user (**user A**) was `_id` 2, and the viewed user, **user B** was `_id` 3:

```
{
    _id: 3,
    name: 'Lucy',
    following: [1, 2],
    is_following: false
}
```

Comment: Not really that clear what you are asking. Perhaps you should actually show by demonstration what kind of result you would be expecting based on a provided data sample ( or the current if you believe it still applies ). There are some things that this "looks like", but showing your expected result for a request would make it much clearer. Also please don't use things like `ObjectId("1")`, which is invalid data and cannot be used by people attempting to solve in a demonstration. Either just show a real `ObjectId` value, or simply use something else valid. Such as `_id: 1` instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Good point regarding the ObjectId's. I've added a couple examples of desired outputs, and hopefully made the question a bit easier to understand.

Comment: So I'm more than a little confused by your expected output since it seems reversed. Which user ( A or B ) are you thinking these results belong to? Just looking at the last one 3 is following 1 and 2, therefore 1 is a follower of 3 and 2 is not. Would you not want `is_following` on each potential follower to see if they were following the "parent" user? Or not? It just seems Odd that you are giving output of 3 with false where that person is in fact following the other. It's the "other" who is not following them.

Comment: Just throwing you an answer. Look at it and if you really think there's something not right about the process then tell me. As far as I can see the logical pattern of what you are asking is that the follower is also following the user, which is what the results demonstrate.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the answer and sorry for the confusion! Each user in the collection holds the users they follow, not who is following them. I'm trying to determine whether the user that is requested, and eventually output (user B), is being followed by the authenticated API user (user A). User B may well follow user A, but only when user A is following user B should the `is_following` field be set to true as the field is intended to be from the authenticated users perspective. "Am I following this person?", rather than "Are they following me?" Hope that helps clear things up :)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't clear it up and I just don't get it. Please comment on the answer about what you don't think is right. But "Am I following user?" as far as I can see is just `find({ "_id": me, "following": user })` with nothing else required. Or in the basic sense, you already have `following`. Really not sure about this because it seems to be going round in circles and you're clarifying things I already know and understand. Sit back and take a good logical look at the expressions. You either want what I have given or a simple query for data which is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear in your question, but you appear to be looking for a simple [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) on the same data with comparison of the resulting users. You probably really only want this for a single user at a time, so the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for that user is generally the "option" here.

There is not much in it other than the standard [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result and then using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to do a comparison with the "parent" `_id` and add the new property to the array.

Ideally with MongoDB 3.6 you can apply [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/):

```
Person.aggregate([
  // { "$match": { "_id": 3 } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Person.collection.name,
    "localField": "following",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "following"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "following": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$following",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            { "is_following": {
              "$in": [ "$_id", "$$this.following" ]
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

And for earlier versions you simply need to name the fields "explicitly" within the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) that you want to return:

```
Person.aggregate([
  // { "$match": { "_id": 3 } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Person.collection.name,
    "localField": "following",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "following"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": 1,
    "following": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$following",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$this._id",
          "name": "$$this.name",
          "following": "$$this.following",
          "is_following": { "$setIsSubset": [["$_id"], "$$this.following"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The basics are as each element is inspected by [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) you can make a comparison of their own `"followers"` array and the current user `_id` value. Either [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) or [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) apply for this sort of comparison. One compares a value to an array and the other "two" arrays.

Alternately where you don't even have access to [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you can `.populate()` and then simply "re-map" the array content in much the same way:

```
let people = await Person.find().lean().populate('following');

people = people.map(p => ({ 
  ...p,
  following: p.following.map(f => ({
    ...f,
    is_following: f.following.some(e => e._id.equals(p._id))
  }))
}));
```

Using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the [`ObjectID.equals()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method in order to do the comparison. Note that [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) cannot apply here without remapping the `ObjectId` values to string due to how "object comparison" works.

All forms here arrive at the same result:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "David",
        "following" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "Sam",
                        "following" : [
                                1
                        ],
                        "is_following" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "Lucy",
                        "following" : [
                                1,
                                2
                        ],
                        "is_following" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "Sam",
        "following" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "David",
                        "following" : [
                                2,
                                3
                        ],
                        "is_following" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "Lucy",
        "following" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "David",
                        "following" : [
                                2,
                                3
                        ],
                        "is_following" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "Sam",
                        "following" : [
                                1
                        ],
                        "is_following" : false
                }
        ]
}
```